# Is there any way to create web API documentation without swagger?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, webapi

I have created a WEB API in Visual Studio 2022, now I want to create documentation/help page for the API but I don't want to use swagger. Is there anyway I can do it?

I tried creating using old methods but all they are either directing me swagger or the nuget packages  which can't be installed in Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Why don't you want to use swagger? There should be nothing that prevents you from creating the OpenAPI documents by hand, but chances are it will be wrong, or outdated fairly quickly.

Comment: We generate swagger docs automatically using [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore). It compiles on VS2022, with .NET5/.NET6 targets.